# Html Table row height gets reduced over the limit

Tags: html, css

Given the HTML below how do I limit the min height of my yellow cell with the blue cell's height - I can't use min-height as blue boxes height is defined in the external style.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
        <table style='background-color: #ccc; width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td id='ry' style="height: 100%; background-color: green;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td id='bx' style='background-color: yellow;'>
                    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style='width: 33.33%; height: 100%;'>
                                <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                    <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                        <div style=" width: 30px; height: 30px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: blue;">?</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't unless JavaScript is an option

Comment: true, but it's the last resort really